# Subdomains Handling Through Main Domain Folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have dynamic subdomains structure, like:

```
sub1.domain.com/file1
sub2.domain.com/file2
...
subn.somain.com/filen
```

I'm looking for a solution on how to display under URL `sub1.domain.com/file1` the result of executing the script located in the main folder - `domain.com/file.php?sub=sub1&file=file1`, without changing the link.

I have tried htaccess but rewrite redirects to `domain.com/file.php?sub=sub1&file=file1` but I need to stay on an initial link.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: You need to use Apache VirtualHost. See it here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html. Tell me if you have any question

Comment: Thank you, Petoux, that's what I think too, I hoped to do it through .htaccess, but guess that only VirtualHosts will work. Thank you.

Comment: I searched a way to get that result with .htaccess, but found nothing! Glad I helped

Comment: All you need is a default host, not separate virtual hosts. In that http host you can use the rewriting module to react on the actual host requested and internally rewrite that request as you like. You _can_ do that in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), but you should always prefer to implement such rules in the real http host configuration for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a default host, not separate virtual hosts. In that http host you can use the rewriting module to react on the actual host requested and internally rewrite that request as you like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /file.php?sub=%1&file=$1 [END]
```

For this to work you need to make sure that your http default host actually serves requests to those host names (you call them "subdomains"). That is independent from the actual rewriting, though.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).